# Rsyslog creating duplicate entries when forwarding application logs

Tags: linux, syslog, rsyslog

I'm trying to add a new application log forward to a host which is already setup to send it's logs to a remote syslog server. I'm following the directions here: http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v7-stable/configuration/modules/imfile.html

The log file is written by an application and doesn't use any of the syslog facilities.

On the sender, I've added these two lines to `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:

```
$ModLoad imfile
$InputFilePollInterval 10
```

I've added a file in `/etc/rsyslog.d/applogger.conf` with the contents below.

```
input(type="imfile"
      File="/var/log/applog"
      Tag="applogger"
      StateFile="statefile2")
```

The logs are forwarded to the central logging system OK, but they are also being replicated into `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/messages` on the **sending** host, cluttering up the logs with lots of extra messages. The link above mentions duplicate entries but this is in regard to unique filenames for the applogs. This is the only file on the system with this name.

I must use `rsyslog` for this, so simply replacing it with `syslog-ng` is not an option.

How can I forward just the entries in `/var/log/applog` without duplicating the entries in the other logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to add this line to applogger.conf. Any unique keyword found in the applog message entry will work.

```
:msg, contains, "appname" stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Centos stream9 has been filtered according to contains. The log is not written to messages, but it is not forwarded at the same time